# How to call many functions in a specific order in react js button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For many reasons I can't define my functions before and call them in my button. I have to define them directly in the button.
This button allow to zoom in a part of an image, then the image should disappear. So I want to call many functions in a specific order. In a first time there were only 2 functions and that worked as following

```
<button id="zoomInButton" disabled={props.has_zoomed != 1} onClick={
     async (x, y, scale, step, animationTime) => {
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            // zoom in
            setTransform(x=-3740, y=-1860, scale=4.25, animationTime=3000)
         }).then(setTimeout(function() {

            // image disapeear with reducing opacity
            $("#village").fadeTo(3000, 0);
         }, 3000))
     }
}>   +    </button>
```

But now I want to add a 3rd function, the one which make the #village totally disappear, by passing hidden to True , I did like that but it doesn't work :

```
<button id="zoomInButton" disabled={props.has_zoomed != 1} onClick={
     async (x, y, scale, step, animationTime) => {
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        // zoom in
        setTransform(x=-3740, y=-1860, scale=4.25, animationTime=3000)
     }).then(setTimeout(function() {

        // image disapeear with reducing opacity
        $("#village").fadeTo(3000, 0);
     }, 3000)).then(setTimeout(function() {

         // for starting I just made an alert
         alert("YES");
     }, 3000))
 }
}>     +     </button>
```

And that's not the expected result, "YES" is displayed automaticall then I can see the ZoomIn & FadeTo

Thank you for reading and helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last then chain on `setTimeout` which is no use. You can add the second `setTimeout` inside the first one as shown below as example. Run the snippet to check the output which shows that the last alert is shown 3 seconds after 2nd one which is shown 3 seconds after the firstone.

```js
const clickMethod = async () => {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // zoom in
    alert("setTransform");
   // setTransform(x=-3740, y=-1860, scale=4.25, animationTime=3000)
 }).then(setTimeout(function() {

    // image disapeear with reducing opacity
    alert("fadein");
    // $("#village").fadeTo(3000, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {

     // for starting I just made an alert
     alert("YES");
 }, 3000)
 }, 3000));

}

clickMethod();
```